# I Want to know how to connect database........?

Tags: android, sql, web-services, sqlite

I am new for Android i want to know how to connect database.I saw one video in you tube and i follow hole video but its not working.i don't know where i made mistake. please help me.from one week an words i'm trying but now also i'm not getting solution please help me stack over flow.

```
class ServerRequests {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=1000*15;
    public static final String       
    SERVER_ADDRESS="http://192.168.1.11/myfolder/new1.php";

    public ServerRequests(Context context){
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait.....");
    }
    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user,GetUserCallbackuserCallback{
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user,userCallback).execute();

    }
    public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user,GetUserCallback callBack){
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsynctask(user,callBack).execute();

    }
    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;
        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user,GetUserCallback userCallback){
            this.user=user;
            this.userCallback=userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair>dataToSend=new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",user.age + ""));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                                                     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                                                                                                  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

            try{
                post.setEntity(new URLEncoderFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onpostExecute(Void aVoid){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

    }
    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,User>{
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;
        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user,GetUserCallback userCallback){
            this.user=user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }
        @Override
                protected User doInBackground(Void... params){
            ArrayList<NameValuePair>dataToSend=new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser=null;
            try{
                post.setEntity(new URLEncoderFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponce httpResponce=client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity=httpResponce.getEntity();
                String result= EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(result);

                if (jObject.length()==0){
                    user=null;
                }else{
                    String name=jObject.getString("name");
                    int age =jObject.getInt("age");

                    returnedUser=new User(name,age,user.username,user.password);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return returnedUser;
        }
        @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }
    }
}





  enter code here

      public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button blogin;
EditText etusername,etpassword;
TextView tvregister;
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    etusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
    etpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
    blogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    tvregister=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_register);
    blogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvregister.setOnClickListener(this);
userLocalStore=new UserLocalStore(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.login_button:
            String username=etusername.getText().toString();
            String password=etpassword.getText().toString();

            User user=new User(username,password);

            authenticate(user);

            userLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
            break;

        case R.id.tv_register:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
private void authenticate(User user) {
    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequests.fetchUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            if (returnedUser == null) {
                showErrorMessage();
            }else {
                logUserIn(returnedUser);
            }

        }

    });
}
    private void showErrorMessage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect user details");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
        dialogBuilder.show();

}
private void logUserIn(User returnedUser){

    userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);

    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
}
```

}

Comment: hello why we are putting Minus marks i don't know

Comment: Use Log.e("TAG",object or string) to trace out error...

Comment: I am not getting...

Comment: Add Log in all methods at starting point and ending point so you can check how much code is executed and when it stops running.

Comment: give me any suggestions which site is good for data base connection for store login and signup

Comment: did you test reference website i provided ?

Comment: sorry @Asp no i'm not getting that their is no complete code that's why (i'm very new for android and i week in database connection so i'm suffering a lot).Thanks

Comment: did your problem solved or yet not ?

Comment: No @ Asp that only i'm saying

Comment: ok i will try now @Asp.........

Comment: @Asp if there is possible please send me all the hole code.(if u have free are if is possible)

Comment: ya sure... drop me personal message

Comment: How can I contact you, I saw your profile also but their is no your contact details.

Comment: I am really sorry. I don't know how to ping you personally. I could not find any option to ping you. Could you please ping me separately so that I could follow you. Thank you.

Comment: @Asp help me please............

Comment: ok I sent a message to you

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link which you can refer for fetching data from server.

For Creating Web Service using PHP  [Click here](http://androidtutorialforbeginners.com/php-webservice-json-generator/)

```
<?php  

    include("connect.php");


    $result="";

    //get data from users (name for user variable is p1 and p2
    //here I am stroing this value to par1 and par2
    //method i am using is GET
    $par1=$_GET['p1'];
    $par2=$_GET['p2'];


    $eve = "select * from table where field1='$par1' and field2='$par2'";

    $re = mysql_query($eve);

    $response = array();
    $posts = array();

    while($rt = mysql_fetch_array($re))
    {
        $f1=$rt['field1'];
        $f2=$rt['field2'];


        break;
    }

    $posts[] = array('p1'=> $f1,'p2'=> $f2);

    $response['posts'] = $posts;
    echo stripslashes(json_encode( array('item' => $posts)));

?>
```

For AsyncTask Example   [Click here](http://androidtutorialforbeginners.com/android-access-json-webservice-using-asynctask/)

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean remember;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preference";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Login Validation

                try {

                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Verifying...");
                    pDialog.show();

                    LoginVerifyTask g = new LoginVerifyTask();
                    g.execute(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString(), ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("cs", "catch error");
                }

            }
        });


        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.newuserregistrationtxtview)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }



    public class LoginVerifyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        String u,p;

        void LoginActivity(String s)
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;

            if (json == null)
            {

                return;
            }

            String csv="";

            try {

                JSONObject js = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray user = js.getJSONArray("item");

                for(int i=0;i<user.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject j2 =  user.getJSONObject(i);

                    //received data
                    String result = j2.get("p1").toString();

                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException js)
            {

            }

            return;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            u = params[0];
            p = params[1];

            String tempdata="";
            String buffer="";

            try
            {


                URL url = new URL("http://websitename.com/folder/webservice.php?p1=" + params[0].replace(" ", "%20") + "&p2=" + params[1].replace(" ", "%20"));
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.connect();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                //buffer = new String();

                if(is==null)
                {
                    return tempdata;
                }
                else
                {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line="";

                    while( (line = reader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        buffer += line;
                    }
                    return buffer;

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("cs", e.toString());
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```